# what method within a ViewController's class can I call to check when it has been brought to the foreground?

Tags: iphone, ios

what method within a ViewController's class can I call to check when it has been brought to the foreground?

For example Im looking at a page on my application and I decide to close the application and go back to it later. When I go back to it the same view as I was looking at was on the screen. However... As soon as I open the application I want to segue over to another view.

How can I do this?

Currently trying this:

```
 - (void) applicationDidBecomeActive:(NSNotification*) notification
{
    [self checkActivity];
    // Do your stuff here
}


- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                 selector:@selector(applicationWillEnterForeground:)
                                                     name:UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification
                                                   object:nil];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                 selector:@selector(applicationDidBecomeActive:)
                                                     name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification
                                                   object:nil];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)checkActivity{
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSLog(@"Checking if re-authentication required...");
    if([[defaults objectForKey:@"shouldgotologin"] isEqualToString:@"yes"]){
        NSLog(@"View Should go to login...performing segue");
        [defaults setObject:@"no" forKey:@"shouldgotologin"];
        [defaults synchronize];
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"backtologin" sender:self];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Should go to login is not true.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Register your view controller to observe `UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification`:

1) Inside view controller's init method:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(applicationWillEnterForeground:)
                                             name:UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification
                                           object:nil];
```

2) Inside view controller's dealloc method:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
```

3) Also, have your view controller implement this method:

```
- (void) applicationWillEnterForeground:(NSNotification*) notification
{
    // This method will be called just before entering the foreground;
    // Do your stuff here
}
```

If the timing of `UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification` doesn't suit you, check all the available notifications for `UIApplication` here:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: i am using ARC. so only step 1 and 3 apply. I tried implementing this method and adding the observer as shown in stpe 1 and 3 but the method isnt being called in my view controller. What do you think could be wrong? I updated the question with the code.

Comment: ok fully added the code now. the function  - (void) applicationDidBecomeActive:(NSNotification*) notification  doesnt appear to be called in the viewcontroller still.

Comment: Weird it isn't being called. Is the 'addObserver...' Part being executed?

Comment: Also, ARC or not you still have to unregister for notifications, I believe (unless NSNotificationCenter keeps zeroing references to each observer), can somebody verify this?

Comment: Again: did you implement the listener method in the same view controller that registers itself as observer?

Comment: I figured it out now... It was just a mistype :P.... it works. you are  a legendary cheese.... a legendairy... -_-' thankyou!

Answer (score 1):

Jump To ApplicationDelegate File, you will find following methods.

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
{

}

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{

}

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{

}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{

}
```

Remember, It is not the viewController who receives the notifications related to the Application states like willResignActive,didEnterBackground,willEnterForeground. ApplicationDelegate object is going to handle those notifications. So, Try putting your logic in above methods.
Hope that helps. If not, add your queries using comments below my answer.

Comment: Ok so lets say I want to perform a segue from the active view controller. How would I do that in the ApplicationDelegate object? (AppDelegate.m). Or how would make the ViewController perform a function when applicationWillEnterForeground has just been performed?

Comment: The vc _can_ be notified (in addition to the app delegate) _if_ he registers for the notifications (see my answer)

Comment: @ranReloaded - Well ! I was talking about default behavior :) No problem. Even your solution looks great. Upvoted ! :)

Comment: Thanks. You can use the app delegate existing methods too. I believe it's a design choice between: having the delegate tell your v.c., or having your v.c. be "self-sufficient" and decoupled.  ;)